# Is it possible to reinstall Android recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, installation

I have a phone which I unlocked the bootloader. Somehow it seems the recovery app disapeared, any chance I can reinstall it from adb or fastboot ?

Comment: There is no "recovery app", I assume you are referring to the recovery partition/ROM. What Android phone are you talking about? The way how a recovery ROM is saved has changed over time, so we need to have more details about your phone.